# Django NoReverseMatch error, dollar sign added to url pattern

Tags: python, django, url

I'm going mad over this error.

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='home'),
    url(r'^(?P<show_id>\d+)/$', views.show, name='show'),
)
```

**index.html:**

```
{% for s in shows %}
    <li><a href="{% url 'serialcharter:show' show_id=2 %}">{{ s.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

**Error:**

```
NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'show' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'show_id': 2}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'$(?P<show_id>\\d+)/']
```

I'm assuming that the problem is that dollar sign at the beginning of the pattern but as you can see in my urls.py there is a caret, not a dollar sign. I tried restarting the server multiple times, changing the url to see if changes are reflected in the error message (they are), use positional parameter instead of named, nothing worked.
Why, where and how does it add that dollar sign to the url pattern? Is that really the problem?

Comment: The dollar sign is not a problem; Django does not find your route by name _at all_, so it does not matter what the regular expression is yet (but it seems ok at first sight). Are you sure you have enabled the `serialcharter` app in your settings, and that the `urls.conf` file you posted is inside the `serialcharter` app's directory?

Comment: Make sure there isn't a dollar in the regex that includes the serialcharter urls.

Comment: @Alasdair, my savior! That was exactly the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that there isn't a dollar in the regex that includes the serialcharter urls.

Comment: After 3 hours of searching and trying did this resolve my problem. +1 :D